# Magento 2 admin panel url 404

Tags: magento-2.1, admin-panel, 404

I have a Magento 2 website and have a custom admin panel url. The admin url was working fine in the past. Then all of a sudden I went to go to the admin panel and noticed that the admin url gives a 404? nothing was changed on the site/server and I even rolled back the server to a prior backup that was a few days before and still the same issue.

When I look in system.log I see the below

```
[2017-08-23 20:35:32] main.INFO: Theme layout update file '/var/www/kisseurope.com/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Smartwave_Porto/layout/default.xml' is not valid.
```

Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 9 and referenceContainer
 Line: 32
Opening and ending tag mismatch: page line 8 and body
 Line: 52
Extra content at the end of the document
 Line: 53 [] []

the contents of the default.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_custom_head" template="html/head.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="porto_newsletter_popup" template="subscribe_popup.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_custom_notice" template="html/custom_notice.phtml" after="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="subscribe_success" template="html/custom/subscribe_success.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_header" template="html/header.phtml" before="main.content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="header_customer_form_login" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/login_popup" template="Smartwave_Porto::html/login.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_block" template="html/header_custom_block.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/static_block" after="-"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="top.search" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="minicart" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="currency" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="logo" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="skip_to_content" destination="porto_header"/>

    <move element="page.top" destination="page.wrapper" after="porto_header"/>

    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="1"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="1"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="1"/>

    <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: try to avoid "_" underscore in folder name

Comment: ya but it has worked with the folder name being an underscore so that can't be the issue.

Comment: it seems like there are 2 times `</referenceContainer>` - that might be the issue

Comment: thanks I removed the extra </referenceContainer> and cleared cache via ssh and still get a 404 for the admin url

Comment: did you check your admin name in `app/etc/env.php` ?

Comment: yes it have the admin name I am trying to use in the env.php file.

Comment: Your frontend working all category page and CMS page?

Comment: Yes all the cms pages and category and product pages all work fine on front end. which is whats so strange.

Answer (score 0):

If it's custom module then you have to add `default.xml` inside your module layout folder.

**Instead of**

```
/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Smartwave_Porto/layout/default.xml
```

**Try this:**

```
app/code/Smartwave/Porto/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

If you are not using any custom module then add `default.xml` in `Magento_Theme` folder

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing tag in your xml

```
</page>
```

for the `<page>` tag which is opened on `line 3`.

Basically the error message is saying that there are errors in the XML. You could use an IDE to load in XSD's to validate the Magento 2 XML's. Check out [Alan Kent's blog](https://alankent.me/2015/10/07/xml-schema-resolution-in-php-storm-with-urns-quick-note/)  how to do that.

You could also use an online XML validator like: https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ (this one also excepts XSD's)